# Reduce $SAT$ to $3SAT$

Tags: np-complete, reductions, polynomial-time

I was reading [this](https://users.fit.cvut.cz/~belohja4/MI-PAA/cv4_SAT-3SAT-and-other-red.pdf) that details a polynomial reduction from $SAT$ to $3SAT$.

In case $k = 1$ or $k = 2$, why don't we just replace those clauses with $C_i' = \{{z_1, y_{i, 1}, y_{i, 2}}\}$ and $C_i' = \{{z_1, z_2, y_{i, 1}}\}$  respectively? Instead, it suggested to replace them by $C_i' = \{(z_1, y_{i, 1}, y_{i, 2}), (z_1, y_{i, 1}, \overline{y_{i, 2}}), (z_1, \overline{y_{i, 1}}, y_{i, 2}), (z_1, \overline{y_{i, 1}}, \overline{y_{i, 2}})\}$ and $C_i' = \{(z_1, z_2, y_{i, 1}), (z_1, z_2, \overline{y_{i, 1}})\}$ respectively.

Comment: "Why don't we just replace those clauses..." What clauses? You haven't defined any clauses. Could you add enough context to your question that it's understandable without having to read the external document you link? (It's fine to link that, for extra context, but reading it shouldn't be the only way of figuring out what you're asking.)

Comment: Please edit your question to make it self-contained, so we don't have to follow some external link to understand your question.  Summarize what we need to know in your question.  For one thing, people shouldn't have to dig through something else to understand what you are asking.  Also, if the link stops working, then your question becomes incomprehensible.  We want to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will (hopefully) be useful to others over time.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the case $k = 1$. Consider the CNF $z_1 \land \lnot z_1$. You suggest replacing it by
$$
(z_1 \lor y_{1,1} \lor y_{1,2}) \land (\lnot z_1 \lor y_{2,1} \lor y_{2,2}).
$$
Hopefully you see the problem now.

Comment: O-Oh, true. Didn't consider that particular case. Thanks.